# Spring JdbcTemplate with parameter returns empty List

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-jdbc

I can't understand what wrong with it, i spent many hours trying to get my String object from method queryForList(..) and all for nothing. So here this stupid sql query:

```
String GET_EMAIL_BY_LDAP = "select ld.LDAP_EMAIL1 from IPS.ldap ld where ld.ldap_login = ?"
```

I have tried this also without '?' parameter and it is works perfectly.

Here is the way, how I use the method:

```
List<String> email = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(GET_EMAIL_BY_LDAP, String.class, userId.toUpperCase());
```

And this version of method also returns empty List:

```
List<String> email = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(GET_EMAIL_BY_LDAP, new Object[]{userId.toUpperCase()}, String.class);
```

P.S. getEmailById("DN270391RKA")   - this is my user id parameter that passed. It hasn't spaces.

Type of ld.LDAP_EMAIL1 field in table is :   NVARCHAR2(381 CHAR)

Comment: Are `ldap_login` and `ldap_email1` strings in the db? Do you get a result if you "hard-code" the user id into the SQL query?

Comment: "I have tried this also without '?' parameter and it is works perfectly." By this sentence I mean that I have tried hard coded parameter and it works.

Comment: What I meant was "hard-code" a user-id, e.g: `"select ... FROM ... WHERE ld.ldap_login='exampleUserId'"`

Comment: I understand what you say. Yes I do.

Comment: May be trivial check if your user id parameter has leading or trailing space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have understood what it was!

ld.ldap_login values in my ( legacy :-D ) table have a tailing spaces. After minor editing of my sql statement it works. I just added TRIM() on this column.

"select ld.LDAP_EMAIL1 from IPS.ldap ld where TRIM(ld.ldap_login) = ?"

So, it seems if it is usual sql statement then when I execute query then oracle database does TRIM() automatically and in case of PreparedStatement doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> email = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(GET_EMAIL_BY_LDAP, String.class, userId.toUpperCase());
```

This line is fully correct so it seems to be either a bad userID or your sql query is not correct.

Best way is to paste your sql query with an existing user id in your query browser and check if you get more than an empty result.

then use the jdbc template again and pass hardcoded previously working user id and check if you get the same results.

or: delete the userid clause and select all not specific to the user id.

Also make sure the ld.LDAP_EMAIL is String representation e.g varchar/text

Comment: When I execute my query in Oracle SQL developer, it works. When I use hard-coded query (without ? param in it) it works. When I use the code above it doesn't work... aaaaahhh%^#$#$$#